# Compiz - Fatal: No composite extension

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, compiz, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm am trying to display ubuntu desktop. After configuration with ccsm, Iactivate composite, Ubuntu Plugin, .... But when I run compiz, I got these errors:

[image]